# Does having a subnormal series with abelian quotient imply being abelian?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and suppose I have a normal series
$$e = U_0 \subseteq U_1 \subseteq ... \subseteq U_n = G$$
with $U_{i-1}$ normal in $U_i$ and with each quotient $U_i/U_{i-1}$ **abelian**.

> Does this imply that $G$ is abelian as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the definition of solvable group. An easy example of a non-abelian solvable group is $S_3$ with
$$1 \subseteq A_3 \subseteq S_3$$
because $A_3 = A_3/1$ is cyclic of order $3$, and $S_3/A_3$ is cyclic of order $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Group of Rotations of a square.

$G=\{ R_0,R_{90},R_{180},R_{270}, H, V, D, D'\}$

Consider the series,

$\{ R_0\} \subset \{ R_0,R_{180}\}\subset \{ R_0,R_{90},R_{180},R_{270}\}\subset G$

Note each $U_i/U_{i-1}$ is of order $2$, hence cyclic(and abelian).

But $G$ isn't abelian.